# Echo in php is not showing up on the web page after form is submitted

Tags: php, html, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 5 and php for this web page.

When I go to the web page and fill in all the spaces and press create account, none of the echos are showing up on the web page. The page just refreshes and just makes a new page like if I just reloaded the page. No text shows up and none of the function are working.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);

?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>AskmanProducts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/signinvaldator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

if ($_POST['registerbtn']) {
    $getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getconfirmpass = $_POST['confirmpass'];

    if ($getuser) {
        if ($getemail) {
            if ($getpass){
                if ($getconfirmpass) {
                    if ($getpass === $getconfirmpass) {
                        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                            require ("connect.php");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if ($numrows == 0) {
                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$getemail'");
                                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                if ($numrows == 0) {

                                    $password = md5(md5("kjfiufj".$getpass."Fj56fj")); 
                                    $date = date("F d, Y");
                                    $code = md5(rand());

                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                                        '', '$getuser', '$password', '$getemail', '0', '$code', '$date'
                                    )");

                                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                    if ($numrows == 1) {

                                        $site = "http://localhost/Projects/project";
                                        $webmaster = "donotreply@askmanproducts.com";
                                        $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                        $subject = "Activate Your Account";
                                        $message = "Thanks For Registering. Click The Link Below To Activate Your Account.\n";
                                        $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                                        $message .= "You Must Activate Your Account To Login.";

                                        if (mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                            echo "You have been registered. You must activate your account from the activation link sent to <b>$getemail</b>";
                                            $getuser = "";
                                            $getemail = "";
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo "An error has occured. You activation email was not sent.";
                                        }

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo "An error has occured. Your account was not created.";
                                    }

                                }
                                else {
                                    echo "There is already a user with that email.";
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                echo "There is already a user with that username.";
                            }

                            mysql_close();
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "You must enter a valid email address to register.";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "Your password do not match.";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo "You must confirm your password to register.";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "You must enter your password to register.";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "You must enter your email to register.";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "You must enter your username to register.";
    }
}
else {

}

$form = "<form action='register.php' method='post'>
<div class='row' style='margin-top:10%'>
    <div align='center'><h2>Create an Account</h2></div>
        <br />
        <div class='medium-6 medium-centered large-centered large-6 columns'>
            <form data-abide>
                <div class='name-field'>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser'></input>

                <div class='email-field'>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type='email' name='email' value='$getemail'></input>

                <label for='password'>Password</label>
                <input type='password' name='pass' value=''></input>

                <label for='confirmPassword'>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type='password' name='confirmpass' value=''></input>
            <br />
            <br />         
            <button type='submit' name='registerbtn'>Create Account</button>
            <a href='login.php' class='button'>Log In</a>
            <br />

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src='js/vendor/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='js/foundation.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).foundation();
</script>
</form>";

echo $form;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well this doesn't help you at all `error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);` this does `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and your code is totally unsafe to use.

Comment: MD5 is cryptographically broken, MySQL_*() is deprecated and you're susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: well i was following a tutorial so maybe its because that is outdated.

Comment: it's an awful tutorial ^

Comment: ah i see. I will find a new one to follow then.

Comment: find the ones using prepared statements and password_hash() and always check for errors on both PHP and MySQL side of things ;-)

Comment: Would you think this tutorial is not outdated and usable? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFbvdbmB4mM

Comment: as I said in my first comment; that piece of code is totally unsafe. a lot of water's gone under the bridge in 30 years... yes... years; and yes, **30** (thirty). It's not a "typo" ;-)

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to learn about cyclomatic complexity and early returns... Just saying...

Comment: @HoboSapiens is correct... MD5 is too fast and allows for hacker software to test million of possibilities against your encryption rapidly. I added a more secure method in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your form has action='register.php' as its destination.  When you do this, by pressing the Submit button, the page will jump to register.php before giving your error checking code any chance to fire.

I recommend you use

```
action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'
```

so that your Submit button keeps you on the same page, then when your error checking process passes, use:

```
header('Location: register.php');
```

Either that, or pass each of your POST variables to register.php where the error checking is carried out.

Comment: [What are PHP_SELF exploits and how to avoid them](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html)

Answer (score 0):

In this solution I have altered your code considerably but I use this logic all the time on my sites. I'll explain the code under it.

## NOTE:

I did review your processing but did not test... Judging from the initial comments you are getting outdated information regarding programming. your mysql query code is outdated and depreciated and you should be making use of parameterised queries as pointed out in the comments by @Dave below this answer.

I suggest you go to youtube and search for pdo tutorials to learn modern methods of querying mysql. The provided code shows how to process forms through jQuery and a processing php file.

## HTML & jQuery

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>AskmanProducts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/signinvaldator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="hidden" name="processRegistrationURL" value="register.php">

<div id="showRegistrationResults" class="row" style="margin-top:10%">
    <div align="center"><h2>Create an Account</h2></div>
        <br />
        <div class="medium-6 medium-centered large-centered large-6 columns">
            <form data-abide>
                <div class="name-field">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" is="user" name="user" value="$getuser"></input>

                <div class="email-field">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="$getemail"></input>

                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value=""></input>

                <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="confirmpass" name="confirmpass" value=""></input>
            <br />
            <br />         
            <button type="submit" id="registerbtn" name="registerbtn">Create Account</button>
            <a href="login.php" class="button">Log In</a>
            <br />
    </div>
</div>


<script src='js/vendor/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='js/foundation.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).foundation();
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#registerbtn" ).click(function(){
        var url = $('#processRegistrationURL').val();       
        var user = $('#user').val(); 
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var pass = $('#pass').val();
        var confirmpass = $('#confirmpass').val();      
        var postit = $.post( url, {
            user:user, 
            email:email,
            pass:pass,
            confirmpass:confirmpass         
        });     
        postit.done(function( data ) {
        var result = data.split('|');
        if(result[0] == 1){alert(result[1]);}
        else if(result[0] == 2){
        $('#showRegistrationResults').html(result[1]);
        }       
        });     
    }); 
});
</script
</body>
</html>
```

There are no form tags... the form processing is handled on `register.php` which is stored in a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="processRegistrationURL" value="register.php">`

I have added `id` to each form and the submit button.

## register.php

```
$getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getconfirmpass = $_POST['confirmpass'];

    if ($getuser) {
        if ($getemail) {
            if ($getpass){
                if ($getconfirmpass) {
                    if ($getpass === $getconfirmpass) {
                        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                            require ("connect.php");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if ($numrows == 0) {
                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$getemail'");
                                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                if ($numrows == 0) {

                                    $password = md5(md5("kjfiufj".$getpass."Fj56fj")); 
                                    $date = date("F d, Y");
                                    $code = md5(rand());

                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                                        '', '$getuser', '$password', '$getemail', '0', '$code', '$date'
                                    )");

                                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                    if ($numrows == 1) {

                                        $site = "http://localhost/Projects/project";
                                        $webmaster = "donotreply@askmanproducts.com";
                                        $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                        $subject = "Activate Your Account";
                                        $message = "Thanks For Registering. Click The Link Below To Activate Your Account.\n";
                                        $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                                        $message .= "You Must Activate Your Account To Login.";

                                        if (mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                            echo "You have been registered. You must activate your account from the activation link sent to <b>$getemail</b>";
                                            $getuser = "";
                                            $getemail = "";
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo "2|An error has occurred. You activation email was not sent. Please refresh this page and try again. If this issue persists please contact administration.";
                                        }

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo "2|An error has occurred. Your account was not created. Please refresh this page and try again. If this issue persists please contact administration.";
                                    }

                                }
                                else {
                                    echo "1|There is already a user with that email.";
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                echo "1|There is already a user with that username.";
                            }

                            mysql_close();
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "1|You must enter a valid email address to register.";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "1|Your password do not match.";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo "1|You must confirm your password to register.";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "1|You must enter your password to register.";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "1|You must enter your email to register.";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "1|You must enter your username to register.";
    }
    else {
        echo "2|WHATEVER YOU WANT TO RENDER IN #showRegistrationResults";
    }
```

When the button is clicked it fires the `jQuery` which in turn passes the form submission to `register.php`

You will notice in each echo there is a 1 or a 2 with a pipe. `echo "1|You must enter your password to register.php";` The echo will return to the jQuery as data.

The jQuery then splits the data at the pipe (|). If `result[0] == 1` the jQuery fires an alert leaving the form intact for corrections to be made. If `result[0] == 2` the jQuery will replace the content of `#showRegistrationResults` which wraps the form (it will replace the form) with the data returned through the echo.

Review the echos on `register.php`. The first two replace the form as an error in processing has occurred. All other return an alert message.

You can toggle these as desired.

## Improve your password security

You can improve your password security with the following code:

```
$hash_key = trim(file_get_contents('PATH-TO/key.dat'));
$password = hash_hmac('sha512', $getpass, $hash_key);
```

`key.dat` simply contains a key: for example: `72093OT7Yw6g0925T9Ly07G6y7WhI2v5`

Hope this helps

Pete

Comment: "the provided code works as is on numerous sites for me". If that's true, then you have numerous sites that are all vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Dave please explain the vulnerability aspects of the code. I certainly do not want to both share and/or run vulnerable code. I am self taught and lack in areas of theory. I complied the working code from answers on this site.

Comment: mysql_query should not be used as it is being deprecated (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Switch to mysqli_query. Also, your input (from form data) is not being sanitised before being used in your SQL. (and don't rely on client side sanitisation. Always do it server side as client side can be bypassed). You should also switch to using parameterised queries for additional protection.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Dave. I was worried for a moment. The mysql query code above is his code. I am running parameterised queries in all my code. I Noted at the top that I did nothing to the mysql query code... just provided the processing jQuery. I tremendously appreciate you input and will edit the note at the top with a warning. Thanks